# Getting only the main name part of the log file

Tags: c++, file, substr

I have a file name stored in a string as logfileName,suppose i pass the name as `"james.log"` then I need to get only the `"james"` part I tried using something like:-

```
int length = logfileName.size(); //calculates the size
```

Now i need some code that only stores the `"james"` part in the string for the later use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::string name = logfileName.substr(0, logfileName.find('.'));
```

Comment: logfilename = "J.Whitehurst.log";  Maybe use rfind()?

Answer (score 0):

If your platform is Windows and portability is not an issue for you, then you could consider using the [splitpath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e737s6tf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) function.